# How to select the entire top row group by some fields using linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I try to select an item from a list, which has the highest frequency for a filed, so I group items based on that filed and sort them descending. Now I want to select the top row.

I tried:

```
    private Rule MatchRule(string cond)
    {

        var results = (from x in rules
                      where x.Cond == cond
                      group x by new { x.Tree.Val , r = x.Tree.Right.Val, l = x.Tree.Left.Val} 
                      into g
                      select new {
                         rule = ???,
                          Count=g.Count(), 
                      }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
        return results[0].rule;
    }
```

What should I use instead of `???` to select all the fields  of an item (the entire item) (the top row).

Comment: What do you mean "all fields", you mean each of the properties?

Comment: Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I must use `First()` to select the entire row

```
private Rule MatchRule(string cond)
{

    var results = (from x in rules
                  where x.Cond == cond
                  group x by new { x.Tree.Val , r = x.Tree.Right.Val, l = x.Tree.Left.Val} 
                  into g
                  select new {
                     rule = g.First(),
                      Count=g.Count(), 
                  }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
    return results[0].rule;
}
```